# Using LINQ to get a diff between a list and insert it back in between?

Tags: c#, linq, asp-classic

Say I have a list like this: 1, 4, 6, 8.

And I want to know the diff in size between each, is there a simple LINQ solution?
So i'd get 3, 2, 2 (because 4-1, 6-4, etc) for a final list of:
1,3,4,2,6,2,8.

Anyone know how I'd code this in linq?
For what I actually need them for, this is a list of structs with DateTime (not int).

Comment: If its a list of `DateTime`, how would you get the difference in between ? It can't contain 3,2... because they are integer values, It can only contain DateTime values.

Comment: I have a method to give a timespan and a corresponding 'length'. 

If I knew how to do it to a list of ints, i'm sure I could make it work for this.

Comment: How do you plan to combine the two results.  If you have dates the differences between two dates is an interval.  You can't mix dates and intervals into the same sequences.  For ints the difference between two ints is another int, so that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another variant - use Aggregate extension like this

```
var s = new List<int>(){1, 4, 6, 8};
var tt = s.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (a, b) => {
             if (a.Count % 2 != 0)
             {
                 a.Add(b - a[a.Count - 1]);
             }
             a.Add(b);
             return a; 
         });
```

**UPDATE** ver 2

```
var s = new List<int>(){1, 4, 6, 8};
var tt = s.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (a, b) => {
             var c = new List<int>(a);
             if (c.Count % 2 != 0)
             {
                 c.Add(b - c[c.Count - 1]);
             }
             c.Add(b);
             return c; 
         });
```

version with foreach

```
var s = new List<int>(){1, 4, 6, 8};
var tt = new List<int>();
foreach(var i in s){
    if (tt.Count % 2 != 0)
        {
            tt.Add(i - tt[tt.Count - 1]);
        }
    tt.Add(i);
 }
```

version with for

```
var s = new List<int>(){1, 4, 6, 8};
var tt = new List<int>(){s[0]};
for (int i=1;i<s.Count,i++){
     tt.Add(s[i] - s[i-1]);
     tt.Add(s[i]);
 }
```

Comment: You're not actually aggregating any data here, you're just `foreach`-ing over the data.  You could use pretty much any operator you want, as most of them iterate the source sequence; you're just relying on the side effects.  You should instead just use a `foreach` loop, to make the intentions of the code clearer.

Comment: @Servy what are the side event?

Comment: The side effect is adding an item to the list.

Comment: @Servy here does not change the original list, here adding in accumulator

Comment: Correct, however you're *mutating* the accumulator, which means you're relying on the side effects of the methods.  If your aggregate function called it's function multiple times for each item, it would break.  That's one easy way to see that it's relying on side effects.  True aggregation wouldn't *mutate* the accumulator, it would instead replace the accumulator with an entirely new item each time, hence the signature of the accumulate method.

Answer (score 1):

So to start with we can use a method that can take any arbitrary sequence and take each item and pair it up with its previous item, which is easy enough to write for the general case of any sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Pairwise<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var previous = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return resultSelector(previous, iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this we can now write:

```
var differences = list.Pairwise((prev, next) => (prev - next));
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to use a zip.

```
var result = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (current, next) => Math.Abs(next - current))
```

This takes a list and that same list without it's first element, and iterates them both while both have an element for the current position, yielding the absolute value of the difference between each pair.

EDIT: Just realized you want it inserted back in. In that case...

```
var result = 
  list
    .Zip(list.Skip(1), (current, next) => new[]{current, current - next, next})
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

...could be what you want, though it's getting messier now. You might be better off zipping into a new object or leaving off the SelectMany so you can have individual collections of `{current, difference, next}`, since those will be easier to deal with.

Comment: Note that this solution iterates the source sequence twice.  For a list that's not a problem, but for other sequences it could be, so you should be wary about applying this to any arbitrary sequence.

Comment: @Servy: As far as I know, this iterates the sequence only once, together. That's why Zip ends when the shorter sequence ends.

Comment: Zip iterates both the source and second sequence.  In this case, that means iterating both `list` and `list.Skip(1)`.  Both of those involve iterating `list`.  If it's an actual list, that's fine, but if it's, say, a DB query then you'll be hitting the database twice, not once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-LINQ solution. I wonder which one performs better!

```
            var l = new List<int>() {1, 4, 6, 13};
            var resultSet = new List<int>();

            var enumerator = l.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            var prev = enumerator.Current;
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                resultSet.Add(enumerator.Current - prev);
                prev = enumerator.Current;
            }
```